# What's the appropriate way of integrating the expression "full stop" into a written sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What's the appropriate way of integrating the expression "full stop" into a written sentence?

For example:

> The USS Enterprise isn't just a great "Galaxy Class" starship, it's a great starship - full stop.

Comment: Make sure that only British English speakers read it. In American English, the phrase (and the name for the punctuation) is _period_. And it's punctuated that way _It isn't just a `X`, it's a `Y`. Period._

Comment: @JohnLawler Ahhh.  The universe makes sense now.

Comment: The driver hit the brakes until the car came to a full stop. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like you would a normal full stop symbol (*"."*) - at the end of lines. Place a comma just before the phrase.

For example, *English is better than any other language, full stop.*

Use it when you are not open in any way to listening to the opposing view.

Comment: Wouldn't a full stop give greater effect? _English is better than any other language. Full stop._